# Uploading relationships between two objects linked with a junction object

Tags: relationships, junction-object

I am setting up an insurance brokerage CRM where a Contact can have multiple Group Policies and a Group Policy can have multiple Contacts. I have these two objects linked with a junction object, called Contact & Grp Policy. I have all Group Policies and I have all Contacts added into SalesForce with no relationship/link between them. Now, I'm trying to create all the relationships between the two by uploading a file containing Contact in column A and Group Policy # in column B but the data import fails.

I've tried uploading to both the Group Policies Object and the Contact & Grp Policy Junction Object.

Here is my Schema. I appreciate any assistance!

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data it is a fairly trivial data load.

you will need:

1. Contact Id/External Id
2. Group & Policy Id/External Id

Create a spreadsheet with a column for the Contact Id and a column for the matching Group Id

Then using data loader, either

1. Insert the data  (If using SF Ids)
2. Upset Data (If using External Ids)

The job is made much easer with External Ids as you do not need to extract and match up the new contact and policy Ids after they were inserted.

If you do not already have External Ids, you can update the contact an policy records with your own external Ids, use them for the junction object then remove the external Ids. I have created fields for this purpose alone before then deleted the fields.

You mentioned you had received an error, it would be helpful to know it.